# What versions of Youtube for Android support fast-forward and rewind?

Tags: youtube

What version(s) of Youtube for Android definitively support fast-forward and rewind? I'm referring to the forwards and backwards buttons in landscape mode that permit you to jump ~10 seconds. I lost this feature after accidentally updating the Youtube app and am seeking a way to restore this functionality. If I can determine what version(s) support the feature, then I'll be able to sideload the correct version.

The only information I've been able to find on the subject [references the introduction of the feature in 10.43.58](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/10/31/youtube-v10-43-cleans-up-some-icons-and-prepares-to-add-fast-forward-and-rewind-apk-teardown-download/.). I've tested 10.43.58 and a number of other versions to no avail. Perhaps the feature has been disabled server-side? Does anyone have any first-hand experience with a version that includes this feature?

Comment: You can download handy tube player.
Ofcourse its more simple than youtube.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the latest version of YouTube app (tested on v11.27.53) has fast-forward and rewind features, but unfortunately *it's not active by default*.

As hinted by the string resources,

```
<string name="accessibility_rewind">Rewind</string>
<string name="accessibility_fast_forward">Fast forward</string>
```

the features only work on **Accessibility mode**.

Try enabling *Switch Access* (or *TalkBack*, but it's a lot noisier) from *Accessibility* on Android's *Settings*. The next time you use YouTube app, fast-forward and rewind buttons are shown beside the play button on the center.

[image: FF and Rewind on YouTube app]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! *Switch Access* disables the screen lock, which is a pretty hard pill to swallow. Just a FYI for anyone else, there's an Xposed module [Youtube swipe to seek](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.blueberry.youtubeswipetoseek) that enables the feature on Lollipop/Marshmallow devices. The most recent Youtube update broke it and the dev hasn't had a chance to look at it yet, but it's working on v11.29.55 and below.

Answer (score 5):

On the latest app, double tap on the left or right of the screen to perform a 10 second rewind or fast forward

(I happened to find this by accident)

Comment: Great find! I'm running v11.47.57 and it works for me also. The latest full release as of present is v12.01.55 (limited release of v12.03.57) so perhaps this feature has been around a while?

Comment: According to [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/12/11/youtube-v11-47-is-testing-double-tap-to-seek-and-it-can-be-enabled-temporarily-apk-download/), apparently it's been there since v11.47.55 (11 Dec 2016), confirming OP's comment.

Comment: Thank you thank you! My headphones have weak shielding and had accidentally done this twice, and I wasn't tapping far enough to the edge in trying to replicate the gesture.